# Adobe Flex: AdvancedDataGrid Grouped columns - Performance

Tags: apache-flex, performance, adobe, advanceddatagrid

When I create a grid with 1000 columns, the ADG performs well. When I create grouping column, the vertical scroll bar performance real bad. 
Say, I have one parent column with 10 child columns inside it. Like this I have total 100 parent columns. When I show 50 rows of records on this table, the horizontal scrollbar takes a lot of time when dragged using the bar.

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    private var dp:Array = [
        { symbol: "ADBE", name: "Adobe Systems Inc.", price: 49.95,high: 40, low: 1, av:23, med: 5 }, <br>
        { symbol: "ADBE", name: "Adobe Systems Inc.", price: 49.95,high: 40, low: 1, av:23, med: 5 }, <br>
        { symbol: "ADBE", name: "Adobe Systems Inc.", price: 49.95,high: 40, low: 1, av:23, med: 5 } <br>
    ];
]]> <br>
</fx:Script>                

<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="col1"  dataField="symbol"/>
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="name"  dataField="name"/>
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="price1">
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="price" dataField="price"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="high" dataField="high"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="low" dataField="low"/>   
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="av" dataField="av"/> 
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="med" dataField="med"/>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
```

Comment: That curly bracket bar can be used to format code easily and nicely.  No need to manually escape all the '<' and '>'

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Grouped columns is very well known to have performance issues.  The best thing you can do is try to optimize every other way (item renderes, data, etc) and hope that helps.  Either that or find another datagrid solution online or create your own ADG.

Comment: I could find an alternative using DataGrid. (in the below link) But this doesnt support edit feature. No item editor available. Can anyone help me making the splitdatagrid columns editable? http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/thinking_about_item_renderers_1.html

Answer (score 0):

mx AdvancedDataGrid has performance issues when it has more columns ..(Scroller performance is bad )

Sometimes it fails on drawing the grid
You can either use spark based flexicious grid or create your own custom spark grid.